# Makefile: kill a process if it is running

Tags: make, ps

I have a makefile like this, that kills a process if it's already running,

```
test: client server
    pgrep myserver && killall myserver
    /build/bin/myserver --background
    /build/bin/myclient --server 127.0.0.1
```

It works if I have a `myserver` started previously. When it's not, `pgrep myserver` just fails with non zero status, and Makefile take it as an error, e.g

```
pgrep myserver && killall myserver
make: *** [test] Error 1
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Don't combine `killall` with `pgrep`. They don't use the same matching rules, so what `pgrep` shows may not be what `killall` kills. Use `pkill`, which is exactly the same as `pgrep` except that it kills the matching processes instead of displaying their PIDs. Beware that if you call both `pgrep` and `pkill`, there's a race condition: by the time `pkill` runs, some processes shown by `pgrep` may have terminated and some new processes may have started. Unless you care about the process IDs, there's no point in calling `pgrep`; you can just call `pkill` directly.

`pkill` returns the status 1 if it doesn't find any process to kill. Either add `-` at the beginning of the command, to tell make to ignore this error, or change the command to `pkill myserver || true` which does exactly the same thing as `pkill myserver` but always returns a success status.

```
test: client server
    pkill myserver || true
    /build/bin/myserver --background
    /build/bin/myclient --server 127.0.0.1
```

Answer (score 7):

You need a `||true` to ensure the first command always returns success.

You can avoid the need for `pgrep` by throwing away stderr; e.g.

```
test: client server
  killall myserver 2>/dev/null || true
  myserver --background
  myclient --server 127.0.0.1
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need to ignore the result of a command in *Make*, you should use the `-` operator like this:

```
test: client server
    -pkill -f myserver
    myserver --background
    myclient --server 127.0.0.1
```

This way *Make* will know you don't care if `pkill` fails, and you don't have to use `||` unnecessarily.

You can also avoid printing the command and the output with `@-` like this:

```
test: client server
    @-pkill -f myserver
    myserver --background
    myclient --server 127.0.0.1
```